# Distinct four elements in G

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that there is no finite group which has four distinct elements $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ such that $x_i^5=e$ where $i=1,2,3,4$.  By Euler function, $\phi(5)=4$. How can we prove it?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: It's not true.  The cyclic group of order $5$ has exactly four (non-trivial)  elements whose fifth power is the identity, and they are certainly distinct.

Comment: I think it is true because phi(5)=4

Comment: Alternativly look at some generators of $\mathbb{F}_5^4$.

Comment: Perhaps the claim is supposed to be, "No finite group has *precisely* four distinct elements $x$ such that $x^5 = e$"?

Comment: Show that there is no finite group which has four distinct elements x 1 ,x 2 ,x 3 ,x 4   such that x 5 i =e  where i=1,2,3,4

Comment: As written above, it cannot be true: consider the group of permutations of $8$ objects and the cycles $(1,2,3,4,5), (2,3,4,5,6), (3,4,5,6,7), (4,5,6,7,8)$. They are distinct and have order $5$.